# only detect in a section of camera preview layer, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles, apple-vision

I am trying to get a detection zone in a live preview on my camera preview layer.

Is it possible for this, say there is a live feed and you have face detect on and as you look around it will only put a box around the face in a certain area for example a rectangle in the centre of the screen. all other faces in the preview that are outside of the rectangle don't get detected?

Im using Vision, iOS, Swift.

Comment: Any thing you come up with, I am trying to do same now ?

Comment: I did the best way I found was to put a guard in the detection area. So create a cgrect if the xCord yCord width and height of the text in the letter highlight function then create another cgrect for your text of interest the area you only want to see them. Then use guard 2ndcgrect.contains(1stcgrect.origin) else {return} put this before seeing the caLayer this will only put outlines around te thing in the text of interest .. https://medium.com/@tonymerritt/hi-peng-27ff127cd659?source=linkShare-8fa3bb4b8b91-1511567697 I posted it here too in coments

Comment: @djay I have also posted my answer to this so you can see it properly

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by adding a guard before the CALayer adding

Before View did load

```
@IBOutlet weak var scanAreaImage: UIImageView!
var regionOfInterest: CGRect!
```

In View did load
scanAreaImage.frame is a image view that I put in via storyboard and this would represent the area I only wanted detection in,

```
let someRect: CGRect = scanAreaImage.frame
        regionOfInterest = someRect
```

then in the vision text detection section.

```
func highlightLetters(box: VNRectangleObservation) {

    let xCord = box.topLeft.x * (cameraPreviewlayer?.frame.size.width)!
    let yCord = (1 - box.topLeft.y) * (cameraPreviewlayer?.frame.size.height)!
    let width = (box.topRight.x - box.bottomLeft.x) * (cameraPreviewlayer?.frame.size.width)!
    let height = (box.topLeft.y - box.bottomLeft.y) * (cameraPreviewlayer?.frame.size.height)!

// This is the section I Added for the rec of interest detection zone.
//////////////////////////////////////////////

    let wordRect = CGRect(x: xCord, y: yCord, width: width, height: height)
    guard regionOfInterest.contains(wordRect.origin) else { return } // only draw a box if the orgin of the word box is within the regionOfInterest

// regionOfInterest being the cgRect you created earlier    
   //////////////////////////////////////////////

    let outline = CALayer()
    outline.frame = CGRect(x: xCord, y: yCord, width: width, height: height)
    outline.borderWidth = 1.0
    if textColour == 1 {
        outline.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }else {
        outline.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }

    cameraPreviewlayer?.addSublayer(outline)
```

this will only show outlines of the things inside the rectangle you created in storyboard. (Mine being the scanAreaImage)

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: how did you normalize CGRect for regionOfInterest from your scanAreaImage?